# Is apache2 using threads or process in ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: server, apache2, php

How can I be certain that apache2 is using processes and not threads to attend requests, in Ubuntu 18.04 ?

I am trying to optimize a PHP website using pthread. After several tests in Windows 10 using XAMP v3.2.1, I confirmed that apache in XAMP uses 150 worker threads. So far, these test blocks the website and causes that apache restarts. So I think that aditional threads slow my execution even more.

My approach is to do the same tests in my Xubuntu 18.04. This is why I need to be certain that apache2 is using processes instead of threads...

Thank you in advance.